Using an X7R capacitor in an analog signal path
I am thinking about choosing a capacitor to implement C60 in the circuit below. The input to the circuit is a pickup coil which measures a sinusoidal signal of interest centered at around 4.5kHz with a small amplitude of approx. 1mV. The output is a differential ADC. The impedance of the coil is around 50Ohms ohmic. C60 forms a low pass pole with the resistance of the pickup coil. I am wondering if it is ok to implement this 500nF capacitance using an X7R MLCC? To my knowledge, the usage of ferroelectric dielectrics is usually not recommended for many analog signal processing applications since the capacitance of these materials can be temperature-dependent and quite nonlinear which causes distortions in the signal.
If I don't care about the temperature dependence of the pole and the distortion caused by the voltage dependent capacitance, can I use an X7R MLCC or should I be aware of any other effects that may cause signal degradation?


What about C61-C62?

Related: Ceramic capacitors microphonic bandwidth

C60-C62 look to be an input filter.  Usually C61,C62 should be ~10x smaller than C60.  This is so that any differential mismatch in them can still be filtered out by C60.  See TI formum: https://e2e.ti.com/support/data-converters-group/data-converters/f/data-converters-forum/1085436/ads1263-guidance-on-designing-common-mode-and-differential-mode-filter-for-adc-input

I am using C61 and C62 to shunt expected common mode pulses to ground.
